# if else in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, if-statement

I have a list `l`:

```
l = [22, 13, 45, 50, 98, 69, 43, 44, 1]
```

For numbers above 45 inclusive, I would like to add 1; and for numbers less than it, 5.

I tried

```
[x+1 for x in l if x >= 45 else x+5]
```

But it gives me a syntax error. How can I achieve an `if` – `else` like this in a list comprehension?

Answer (score 814, accepted):

```
>>> l = [22, 13, 45, 50, 98, 69, 43, 44, 1]
>>> [x+1 if x >= 45 else x+5 for x in l]
[27, 18, 46, 51, 99, 70, 48, 49, 6]
```

Do-something if `<condition>`, else do-something else.

Comment: Probably should use a different variable than `x` as the condition in the explanation at the bottom, since `x` is used in the example not as the condition.

Comment: what about only including variable in the list if a condition is met? would the else just be pass?

Comment: it seems that the conditional can also go at the end for example extracting objects with a specific condition (name in this example) `var_list = [v for v in tf.all_variables() if v.name == 'C:0']`

Comment: I found that if putting the condition in the beginning, then it requires both if and else (it must yield an element) - but putting it at the end, requires the if only (you can't put an else there).

Comment: @Jeppe Correct, which is an important distinction. If you only want to keep certain elements (ie: you do not necessarily want an entry to the array from every iteration) then you need to put the condition at the end.

Comment: another example of this if you just want to check for only one condition `[x*x for x in list(range(1,6)) if x%2!=0]`

Answer (score 353):

The reason you're getting this error has to do with how the list comprehension is performed.

Keep in mind the following:

```
[ expression for item in list if conditional ]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
for item in list:
    if conditional:
        expression
```

Where the `expression` is in a slightly different format (think switching the subject and verb order in a sentence).

Therefore, your code `[x+1 for x in l if x >= 45]` does this:

```
for x in l:
    if x >= 45:
        x+1
```

However, this code `[x+1 if x >= 45 else x+5 for x in l]` does this (after rearranging the `expression`):

```
for x in l:
    if x>=45: x+1
    else: x+5
```

Comment: My code **user_albums = [{'albums': links['link']} for links in _details['albums']['data'] if 'link' in links.keys() else pass]** getting error for pass in else condition

Comment: @shihon No need for the `else pass` in a list comprehension; it's implied that you don't want the `{'albums': links['link']}` item included in the list when the condition `if 'link' in links.keys()` is met. Correct format: `user_albums = [{'albums': links['link']} for links in _details['albums']['data'] if 'link' in links.keys()]`

Comment: that means, if data isn't exist or null it handle this exception from its ownself??

Comment: @shihon When `'link' in links.keys()` is `False`, a Python list comprehension skips over the expression to add `{'albums': links['link']}` to the list. Your code expanded would behave the same way as `[x+1 for x in l if x >= 45]` in my answer above.

Comment: So, if there is an `else` in the `if` statment, the `for` goes in the end, but if there is no `else` the `for` goes after the initial expression?

Answer (score 307):

```
[x+1 if x >= 45 else x+5 for x in l]
```

And for a reward, here is the comment, I wrote to remember this the first time I did this error:

> Python's conditional expression is `a if C else b` and can't be used as:
>
> ```
> [a for i in items if C else b]
> ```
>
> The right form is:
>
> ```
> [a if C else b for i in items]
> ```
>
> Even though there is a valid form:
>
> ```
> [a for i in items if C]
> ```
>
> But that isn't the same as that is how you filter by `C`, but they can be combined:
>
> ```
> [a if tC else b for i in items if fC]
> ```

Comment: @Dan D. What about muliple `if`s? ie `[x+1 if x >= 45 x-1 if x<10 else x+5 for x in l]` ? I have a similiar kind of [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582695/printing-certain-strings-different-colour-with-termcolor-colored) with the if statement

Comment: @3kstc: For that: `[x+1 if x >= 45 else (x-1 if  x < 10 else x+5) for x in l]`. I'll look at your question.

Comment: @Dan D. Thanks 
The right form is:
[a if C else b for i in items]
this work for me.

Comment: Not OP but thanks for your answer. For your last line of code, could you explain a bit for me what `for i in items if fC` does please? Does it mean that you are only using the `a if tC else b` conditional on the elements in `items` that can make `fC` true? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu Yes. The point was to show the difference between the `if` in the ternary `A if C else B` and the conditional `if` in `i for i in items if p(i)`. Every comprehension can be written as statements if you name the result. `v = [A if q(i) else B  for i in L if p(i)]` becomes `v = []`, `for i in L: if p(i): v.append(A if q(i) else B)`.

Answer (score 146):

You must put the expression at the beginning of the list comprehension, an if statement at the end filters elements!

```
[x+1 if x >= 45 else x+5 for x in l]
```

Comment: +1 for explicitly distinguishing the role of conditionals at the beginning of the comprehension vs. at the end. You can do both at the same time, too; e.g. `['upper' if item.isupper() else 'lower' for item in 'Omg! paNCAkEs!!!' if item.isalpha()]`

Comment: Great! Thank you, Is there an option to use else if

Comment: @vinSan If you want to go as far as using an elif in your list comprehension, you're likely to have already surpassed the level of complexity a list comprehension was intended to be used for. Put your logic in a function and call it from your list comprehension instead.

Answer (score 41):

Like in `[a if condition1 else b for i in list1 if condition2]`, the two `if`s with `condition1` and `condition2` doing two different things. The part `(a if condition1 else b)` is from a lambda expression:

```
lambda x: a if condition1 else b
```

while the other `condition2` is another lambda:

```
lambda x: condition2
```

Whole list comprehension can be regard as combination of `map` and `filter`:

```
map(lambda x: a if condition1 else b, filter(lambda x: condition2, list1))
```

Comment: Quite a good mapping to `map` and `filter` for two conditional snippets.

Comment: can we have list comprehension without a for loop and just if/else to put a single default value inside the list and later extend it if required? i.e. result = `[ 'hello' if x == 1 ]`. This is giving a syntax error.

Answer (score 22):

You can also put the conditional expression in brackets inside the list comprehension:

```
    l = [22, 13, 45, 50, 98, 69, 43, 44, 1]
    print [[x+5,x+1][x >= 45] for x in l]
```

[false,true][condition] is the syntax

Answer (score 17):

I just had a similar problem, and found this question and the answers really useful. Here's the part I was confused about. I'm writing it explicitly because no one actually stated it simply in English:

*The iteration goes at the end.*

Normally, a loop goes

```
for this many times:
    if conditional: 
        do this thing
    else:
        do something else
```

Everyone states the list comprehension part simply as the first answer did,

```
[ expression for item in list if conditional ]
```

but that's actually not what you do in this case. (I was trying to do it that way)

In this case, it's more like this:

```
[ expression if conditional else other thing for this many times ]
```

Answer (score 6):

You could move the conditional to:

```
v = [22, 13, 45, 50, 98, 69, 43, 44, 1]
[ (x+1 if x >=45 else x+5)  for x in v ]
```

But it's starting to look a little ugly, so you might be better off using a normal loop. Note that I used `v` instead of `l` for the list variable to reduce confusion with the number 1 (I think `l` and `O` should be avoided as variable names under any circumstances, even in quick-and-dirty example code).