# Trying to understand Python code with generator expression

Tags: python, generator

In the following code:

```
chars = set('AEIOU')
...
if any((cc in chars) for cc in name[ii]):
    print 'Found'
```

What is the "(cc in chars)" part?  I know that it is applied to each cc that is generated by the for loop.  But is the "(cc in chars)" construct itself a generator expression?

Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to get which characters in a word are vowels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `(cc in chars)` part is a boolean expression; [`in` is a sequence operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) that tests if `cc` is a member of the sequence `chars`. The parenthesis are actually redundant there and could be omitted.

Comment: Amazing, tried it w/o parenthesis, and you're right, they are not needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`(cc in chars)` simply checks if the string `cc` is contained in `chars` and returns a boolean `false` or `true`.

According to the [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), something in-between parentheses is not a generator expression unless it has at least one `for i in iterable` clause.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation for the generator expression is MUCH appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `(cc in chars)` is merely a boolean that returns True if cc is in chars and False otherwise.

In fact, the code could actually be written

```
chars = set('AEIOU')
...
if [cc for cc in name[ii] if cc in chars]:
    print 'Found'
```

In that case, if the list has any elements (making it pass the if-clause), that's because some cc is in chars. I'd actually find that to be more readable and straightforward.
Cheers.

**EDIT:**

To clarify my answer, `[cc for cc in name[ii] if cc in chars]` generates a list of all characters in name[ii] that in 'chars' (in that case, vowels). If this list has any elements on it, it'll pass the if-test.

`[cc for cc in name[ii] if cc in chars]` says "for each element/character in name[ii], add it only if it's in chars. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension/4406777#4406777) answer for clarification.

Comment: FRD, I tested your code, yes it works, but I don't understand how. :(

Comment: Sabuncu, do you understand what is a list comprehension?

Comment: OK, I see it now.  It's a list comprehension w/ square brackets.  Thanks for the edit and the hint.