# Generator stuck in an infinite loop inside a list comprehension?

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

This works fine:

```
>>> def my_range(stop):
    i = 0
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += 1

>>> [k for k in my_range(10) if k < 5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now I modify my generator:

```
>>> def my_range():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

>>> result = []
>>> for k in my_range():
    if k < 5:
        result.append(k)
    else:
        break


>>> print(result)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now, why is this trapped in an infinite loop? Even though I have k < 5. Aren't generators supposed to iterate only when next is called?

```
>>> [k for k in my_range() if k < 5]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The condition in an LC doesn't imply a `break` when it returns false; if you want that behavior then look into `itertools`, specifically `takewhile()`.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406777/139010) explains it well:

> Keep in mind the following:
>
> ```
> [ expression for item in list if conditional ]
> ```
>
> Is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> for item in list:
>     if conditional:
>         expression
> ```

which means that your list comprehension:

```
[k for k in my_range() if k < 5]
```

is equivalent to:

```
for k in my_range():
    if k < 5:
        k
```

Now it should be clear why this never terminates: there's nothing to actually `break` the infinite loop.

Comment: Is there a way to `break` and make the list comprehension stop taking values from the generator? Preferably without using `itertools`

Comment: @Michael why without using `itertools`?