# List comprehension with if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension

I want to compare 2 iterables and print the items which appear in both iterables.

```
>>> a = ('q', 'r')
>>> b = ('q')


# Iterate over a. If y not in b, print y.
# I want to see ['r'] printed.
>>> print([ y if y not in b for y in a])
                              ^
```

But it gives me a invalid syntax error where the `^` has been placed.
What is wrong about this lamba function?

Comment: all answers below are right, but also `b = ('q')` doesn't create a tuple. Tuples with one element need an explicit `,`, that is `b = ('q',)`

Comment: I have changed `tuples` into `iterables`.

Comment: _"What is wrong about this lamba function?"_ ...there is no lambda function here

Answer (score 259, accepted):

You got the order wrong. The `if` should be after the `for` (unless it is in an `if-else` ternary operator)

```
[y for y in a if y not in b]
```

This would work however:

```
[y if y not in b else other_value for y in a]
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension about an if else statement in a lambda function. And I thought that using only the if statement (without the else) would work in the same order.

Answer (score 53):

You put the `if` at the end:

```
[y for y in a if y not in b]
```

List comprehensions are written in the same order as their nested full-specified counterparts, essentially the above statement translates to:

```
outputlist = []
for y in a:
    if y not in b:
        outputlist.append(y)
```

Your version tried to do this instead:

```
outputlist = []
if y not in b:
    for y in a:
        outputlist.append(y)
```

but a list comprehension *must* start with at least *one* outer loop.

Answer (score 9):

list comprehension formula:

```
[<value_when_condition_true> if <condition> else <value_when_condition_false> for value in list_name]
```

thus you can do it like this:

```
[y for y in a if y not in b]
```

Only for demonstration purpose :
    [y if y not in b else False for y in a ]

Comment: You can't put an `else` in a list comprehension, not where you put one at least. Don't confuse a list comprehension (filtering), with a conditional expression (which must have a value, making the else expression mandatory).

Comment: Agree. `else` be used in list comprehension though as shown in the code.

Comment: That's a *conditional expression*. It can be used anywhere a valid expression is applicable. It has not specific to list comprehensions.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a lambda function. It is a list comprehension.

Just change the order:

```
[ y for y in a if y not in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use sufficiently big list `not in b` clause will do a linear search for each of the item in `a`. Why not use set? Set takes iterable as parameter to create a new set object.

```
>>> a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
>>> b = ["c", "d", "f", "g"]
>>> set(a).intersection(set(b))
{'c', 'd'}
```