# Python For Not In

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a dict `test` declared:

```
test = {'test1': 1, 'test2': 2, 'test3': 3}
```

And I want to make a copy of `test` filtering out specific keys that may or may not exist.

I tried the following:

```
test_copy = {k: test[k] for k not in ('test3', 'test4')}
```

However Python does not seem to like `for not in` loops.  Is there any way to do this nicely in one line?

I do not believe this question is a duplicate of
[List comprehension with if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474933/list-comprehension-with-if-statement)
because I was searching for more than a few minutes specifically for dicts.

Comment: Hmm, I closed this, but in retrospect it might not be the correct duplicate to close it against...

Comment: this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1747827/2187558

Comment: I am relatively new to python but have experience with other languages.  I feel like my question is specific to my particular problem rather than the umbrella questions other people had that might not come up in searches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The dictionary comprehension `test_copy = {k: test[k] for k in test if k not in EXCLUDED_KEYS}` will accomplish the copying.

Comment: Thank you!  I tried almost the same thing without the 'in test'.

Answer (score 4):

You need to state the "not in" in the conditional:

```
test_copy = {k: test[k] for k in test if k not in ('test3', 'test4')}
```