# String matching in lists - Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list like below - from this i have filter the tables that begin with 'test:SF.AcuraUsage_' (string matching)

```
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150311
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150312
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150313
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150314
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150315
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150316
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150317
test:SF.ClientUsage_20150318
test:SF.ClientUsage_20150319
test:SF.ClientUsage_20150320
test:SF.ClientUsage_20150321
```

I am using this for loop but not sure why it does not work:

```
for x in list:
 if(x  'test:SF.AcuraUsage_'):
   print x
```

I tried this out:

```
for x in list:
  alllist = x

vehiclelist = [x for x in alllist if x.startswith('geotab-bigdata-test:StoreForward.VehicleInfo')]
```

Still i get the error ' dictionary object has no attribute startswith'.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [List comprehension with if statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474933/list-comprehension-with-if-statement)

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't name your list `list`, since it overrides the built-in type `list`

But, if you'd like to filter that list using Python, consider using this list comprehension:

```
acura = [x for x in list if x.startswith('test:SF.AcuraUsage')]
```

then, if you'd like to output it

```
for x in acura:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are good for that.

Get a list with all the items that begin with 'test:SF.AcuraUsage_' :

```
new_list = [x for x in list if x.startswith('test:SF.AcuraUsage_' ')]
```

Or the items that do *not* begin with 'test:SF.AcuraUsage_' :

```
new_list = [x for x in list if not x.startswith('test:SF.AcuraUsage_' )]
```

Comment: I get the error "Table has no attribute StartsWith'. Sorry guys, i thought this statement returns a list, but it returns a table object. 

list = bq.DataSet('bigdatatest:SF')

This statement returns a list of tables as shown in my question.

Comment: If you want to filter a a very large list (millions of rows) and you are getting it from a iterator, it may be better to use a generator function and yield the resulting data rows. So you don't have to load it all into memory at once and then make a copy of part of it.

Comment: If those items are objects, the filtering still works in a similar way. Just filter on some attribute.

Comment: I tried iterating through the table and storing in a list. Then i iterated through the list for the check. Still I get the error ' dictionary object has no attribute startswith'. I have added that code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

using re module:

```
import re
for x in list:
  ret = re.match('test:SF.AcuraUsage_(.*)',x)
  if ret:
    print(re.group())
```