# Getting the first int value of a tuple but the first value is a string (Error) Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the first int value from all of the tuples in my dictionary keys. The problem is I keep getting the error: "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Population'" The code I am using is

`print([int(item[0]) for item in self.countryCat.values()])`

Is there any way I can skip over the first value in my tuple which is "Population" so I will not get this error anymore? I have been stuck on this forever.

Thanks!

Comment: Not without seeing a representative sample of your dictionary. Please include this as an edit.

Comment: Is using **list comprehensions** mandatory? What is the rush?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a generator that filters out the values that can't be cast to `int`s

```
def error_map(f, iterable):
    for item in iterable:
        try:
            yield f(item)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

Then we can

```
print(list(error_map(lambda x: int(x[0]), self.countryCat.values())))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use list comprehension, you need to make it a conditional list as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474933/list-comprehension-with-if-statement) and then for your condition, create a function that returns true/false if the string can be converted to a string as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/python-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except)

```
def represent_int(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return 

print([int(item[0]) for item in self.countryCat.values() if represent_int(item[0])])
```