# Stacking inline For plus If else

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a line that should sum up all numbers of a string except 0. On a zero it should add 5.

Whats wrong with

```
s="123450"
o=sum([int(x) for x in s if int(x) != 0 else 5])
```

it gives syntax error, but

```
s="123450"
o=sum([int(x) for x in s if int(x) != 0])
```

works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if` at the end of a list comprehension is used as a filter.  It can only cause values to be dropped, not replace them with other things.  To map values, you have to move the `if`/`else` earlier in the comprehension:

```
o=sum([int(x) if int(x) != 0 else 5 for x in s])
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for the first case if -

```
s="123450"
o=sum([int(x) if int(x) != 0 else 5 for x in s ])
print(o)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
20
```

There are many good answers already available on StackOverflow over *if-else in list comprehension*. Check these -

- [if else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)
- [List comprehension with if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474933/list-comprehension-with-if-statement)
- [if/else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension/4260304)

Answer (score 1):

More of an aside really (as the general issue of how you are using `if` inside list comprehensions is well covered in other answers), in this particular case you could do the following:

```
o = sum(int(x) or 5 for x in s)
```

This works because `or` will use the first value if it is "true" (which in the case of integers means non-zero) or the second value if the first is "false" (here, 0).

The other difference here is that I've used a generator expression instead of a list comprehension -- there is no need to build a list just in order to sum the values.

Comment: @alani I dont really get what the expression to evaluate to "true" is. Could you elaborate this?