# Declare array with "where"

Tags: python, arrays

There is in Python option to declare array like this?

`arr = [x for x in vec where x < 2]` - (Edit: sorry for the 'from'. my common mistake (the eclipse always repair me))

(or another statement without real loop)

Comment: possible duplicate of [if else in a list comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `if` instead:

```
arr = [x for x in vec if x < 2]
```

And note that it is a `for` loop, the `from` keyword does not exist.