# Make this code look more elegant

Tags: python, encryption

I am absolutly new in python and in programing, I made this  [bifid cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifid_cipher), I'd like to hear opinions about how to improve and make it look more elegant, thanks in advance.

I been taking courses in Codecademy and Udacity, and I've learn quite a lot.

```
import itertools


#Genera coodernadas-Generate Coordinates
coordinates = [[x,y] for x in range(1,6) for y in range(1,6)]

#Genera alfabeto-Generate Alphabet
alfa = []
for i in range(97,123):
    alfa.append(chr (i))
alfa.remove("i")

#Genera diccionario de coordenadas y alfabeto - Generate dictionary and coordinates alphabet 
alfacor = {}
alfacor = dict(zip(alfa,coordinates))


#Leer Txt - Read txt
document = open("Z:\\R\\Desktop\\BIFIDO\\easy.txt")
contenido = document.read()
print (contenido)
document.close()

#Encripta fase1 - Get's coordinates of txt
encripta = []
for e in contenido:
    encripta.append(alfacor[e])

#Unir lista encripta - Merge content of encropita in a new list
merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(encripta))

#Divido lista merge en partes iguales - Divide meged list to get new coordinates
B = merged[:len(merged)/2]
C = merged[len(merged)/2:]

#Unir B y C - Zip B and C to get a new list of coordinates
zipped = zip(B,C)

#Make a new list from zipped to convert from tuple to list
final_list = [list(elem) for elem in zipped]

#Convert contect of alfacor to tuples
inv_alfacor = {}
for letter, coordinate in alfacor.iteritems():
inv_alfacor[tuple(coordinate)] = letter

#Substitude coordinates of final_list from elements of inv_alfacor
encripta_f = []
for element in final_list:
    element = tuple(element)
    if element in inv_alfacor:
        encripta_f.append(inv_alfacor[element])

print "Tu palabra ",encripta_f
```

Comment: This question looks more on-topic for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Asking for opinions about code style is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, did not know about it, will take on mind in futher posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than perhaps using comprehensions and avoid the unnecessary tuple -> list -> tuple conversions, reduce the number of intermediate variables then it might be slightly easier to read. I would also consider making it a function that you pass in a string and an encrypted string is returned:

```
from itertools import chain, product

def bifid(data):
    # Leave coordinates as tuples and appropriate use of itertools.product
    coordinates = product(range(1, 6), repeat=2)

    # Using comprehensions and generators to construct the list/dicts vs loops
    # Leave alfa as a generator as it is only used once
    alfa = (chr(i) for i in range(97, 123) if chr(i) != 'i')
    alfacor = dict(zip(alfa, coordinates))
    inv_alfacor = {coordinate: letter for letter, coordinate in alfacor.iteritems()}
    encripta = (alfacor[e] for e in data)

    merged = list(chain(*encripta))
    final_list = zip(merged[:len(merged)//2], merged[len(merged)//2:])

    return "".join(inv_alfacor[e] for e in final_list if e in inv_alfacor)

# Use with it closes automatically and handles exceptions correctly
with open("Z:\\R\\Desktop\\BIFIDO\\easy.txt") as document:
    data = document.read()]

print "Tu palabra: {}".format(bifid(data))
```

Output:

```
"helloworld" -> Tu palabra: kmcyobnalt
```

Comment: I am really impress about code reduction, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use **`with`** statement

You can read more in [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) or in this article [Understanding Python's "with" statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Suggested modification:

```
#Leer Txt - Read txt
with open("Z:\\R\\Desktop\\BIFIDO\\easy.txt", "r") as document:
    contenido = document.read()
    print (contenido)
```

2. Use **list comprehensions**

More info in [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or in the tutorial [Python Tutorial: List Comprehensions](http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php)

Suggested modification:

```
#Genera alfabeto-Generate Alphabet
alfa = [chr(i) for i in xrange(97, 123) if chr(i) != "i"]
```

*(Note, please, this change also includes a condition in the list comprehension - [example at SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension))*

And also:

```
#Encripta fase1 - Get's coordinates of txt    
encripta = [alfacor[e] for e in contenido]
```

3. Use **generators**

The first thing you can start with is following. When you write a list comprehension and you know you are going to iterate only one item of the list a time, change the brackets from `[]` to `()`. This is really simplified but it is the first thing you can do. Another related tip, when you use `range(x)` just like `for i in range(x)`, use `xrange(x)` instead. `xrange` is a generator version of `range`.

More info in [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Suggested change:

```
#Make a new list from zipped to convert from tuple to list
final_list = (list(elem) for elem in zipped)
```

4. **Printing**

In this case, using the print you used is fine, but have a look at string formatting.

More in [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and a [few examples here](https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/new-str-format.html).

Possible change:

```
print "Tu palabra {}".format(encripta_f)
```

5. You **don't need to initialize all** the variables.

You don't need to initialize `alfacor` dictionary when you assign a completely new value to the variable. However, you need to initialize variable when you work with it later.

Thus there is a difference between

```
# no need for initialization
alfacor = {}
# because you assign a new value here to the variable `alfacor`
alfacor = dict(zip(alfa,coordinates))
```

and this:

```
# you need to initialize this
alfacor = {}
# because you are working with the empty dictionary here
alfacor["my_key"] = "my_value"
```

Comment: You should get rid of the extra open in the with statement

Comment: @Marek Wow, thanks a lot for the detail explanation, this will really help in the near future.

Comment: @etsous Glad I could help. Have a look at this tutorial [Code Like a Pythonista: Idiomatic Python](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html) It is probably the most helpful Python material I have ever read.