# Unexpected replacement of zero in Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, behavior

I was looking at a stackoverflow question ([if else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)) and decided to try the following line

`[ a if a else "Exception" for a in range(10) ]`,

and got the following list

`[ "Exception", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]`

as an output. I had expected the output to be

`[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]`

because zero is itself, just as the other numbers  were evaluated. Thinking to test whether the behavior was affecting only the first index, I tried

```
[ a if a else "Exception" for a in range( 1, 10 ) ]
```

which outputed

`[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]`

and was what I would have not expected if the behavior was specific to the first index. Given the results so far, I tried the following thinking there was something particular about `0` being in the iterable.

`[ a if a else "Exception" for a in [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ]`

and

`import numpy
[ a if a else "Exception" for a in numpy.zeros(10) ]`

which resulted in the following for both cases

`[ "Exception", "Exception", "Exception", "Exception", "Exception", "Exception", "Exception", "Exception", "Exception", "Exception" ]`

If someone could explain this behavior to me, I would appreciate it. It *appears* that `0` being in the iterable could be triggering the unexpected behavior, but I am not confident on that conclusion.

Comment: Read the [documentation on this topic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Comment: Thank you @TigerhawkT3, +1 for giving a reference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python treats 0 as false and any other number as true.

Try it for yourself:

```
if 0: print("0 is false")
if 1: print("1 is true")
if 2: print("2 is true")
```

The output you get is:

`1 is true`

`2 is true`

What your list compression is saying is:

"For each number from 0 to 9, if a is true, add a to the list, if a is false, add "Exception" to the list"

Because 0 is treated as False you get "Exception" for 0, then 1 2 3... etc for all the other numbers.

Comment: Thank you! I also tried ` [ a if not a else "Exception" for a in iterable ] `, for each iterable I tried above, and gave consistent behavior with the explanation of '0' as 'False' and '1' as 'True'.

Answer (score 2):

`0` is among the numeric type treated as `False`, same as `[] Empty List` and many others, so in your expression in list compression, the `0` is a `False` condition leading to the result of `Exception` string

You can check it with IDLE:

```
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(1)
True
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool([1,2])
True
```

Comment: That is interesting to me that an empty list evaluates as 'False', and a non-empty list returns as 'True'. Amusingly, but consistently, bool([0]) evaluates as 'True'. I tried your suggestions in my command line, and confirmed your results. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `0` evaluates to `False` in python. All the other numbers would evaluate to `True` and thus be placed in the list.

Lets take a look at this.

```
[ a if a else "Exception" for a in range(10) ]
```

`range(10)` evaluates to 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

0 -> `False`

All other numbers -> `True`