# Convert a list of strings to either int or float

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks something like this:

```
['1', '2', '3.4', '5.6', '7.8']
```

How do I change the first two to `int` and the three last to `float`?

I want my list to look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8]
```

Answer (score 15):

Use a [conditional inside a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4406389/4099593)

```
>>> s = ['1', '2', '3.4', '5.6', '7.8']
>>> [float(i) if '.' in i else int(i) for i in s]
[1, 2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8]
```

Interesting edge case of exponentials. You can add onto the conditional.

```
>>> s = ['1', '2', '3.4', '5.6', '7.8' , '1e2']
>>> [float(i) if '.' in i or 'e' in i else int(i) for i in s]
[1, 2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8, 100.0]
```

Using [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) is the best as it takes care of all the edge cases (mentioned by [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322401/steven-rumbalski) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130279/convert-a-list-of-strings-to-int-and-float/33130297?noredirect=1#comment54072755_33130297))

```
>>> s = ['1', '2', '3.4', '5.6', '7.8']
>>> [int(i) if i.isdigit() else float(i) for i in s]
[1, 2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8, 100.0]
```

Comment: Because of `int("1e2")`

Comment: Different conditional would address Cong Ma's concern: `int(i) if i.isdigit() else float(i)`

Comment: @CongMa:  While it's true that this would fail with `int("1e2")`, I don't think it's downvote worthy.  While worth calling out I think it's outside of the problem specification.

Comment: In Python code LBYL must be assumed downvote-worthy until proven otherwise.

Comment: @CongMa what? That's ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

Use a helper function:

```
def int_or_float(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return float(s)
```

Then use a list comprehension to apply the function:

```
[int_or_float(el) for el in lst]
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)?

```
import ast

[ast.literal_eval(el) for el in lst]
```

Should handle all corner cases. It's a little heavyweight for this use case, but if you expect to handle any Number-like string in the list, this'll do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use *isdigit* method of string:

```
numbers = [int(s) if s.isdigit() else float(s) for s in numbers]
```

or with map:

```
numbers = map(lambda x: int(x) if x.isdigit() else float(x), numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def st_t_onumber(x):
    import numbers
    # if any number
    if isinstance(x,numbers.Number):
        return x
    # if non a number try convert string to float or it
    for type_ in (int, float):
        try:
            return type_(x)
        except ValueError:
            continue

l = ['1', '2', '3.4', '5.6', '7.8']

li = [ st_t_onumber(x) for x in l]

print(li)

[1, 2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display as the same list append the list by using the following query:

```
item = input("Enter your Item to the List: ")
shopList.append(int(item) if item.isdigit() else float(item))
```

Here when the user enters int values or float values it appends the list shopList and stores these values in it.