# Convert a List of string to Int or Float as available

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have list as:

```
list = ['67.50', '70.00', '72.50', '75.00', '77.50', '80.00', '82.50']
```

I want to check if the string is a foat then it should be converted to float
and if the string is a int then it should be converted to int.

Desired Output:

```
list = [67.50, 70, 72.50, 75, 77.50, 80, 82.5]
```

Comment: There is a nice list (perhaps outdated, but instructive) about what may and may not parse as a float. But in your case, it may be sufficient to see if there is a decimal point in the number and if not, parse as int else float: `[float(n) if '.' in n else int(n) for n in list]`

Comment: that one is close too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130279/convert-a-list-of-strings-to-either-int-or-float

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make use of `float.is_integer()`:

```
>>> lst = ['67.50', '70.00', '72.50', '75.00', '77.50', '80.00', '82.50']
>>> [int(x) if x.is_integer() else x for x in map(float, lst)]
[67.5, 70, 72.5, 75, 77.5, 80, 82.5]
```

Comment: That map(float, lst) is smart. I also agree with using lst, instead of list as the variable name as list is also a built-in function of Python.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way using a list comprehension, and checking if the modulo operator of a given string converted to float is `0.0`, to either convert it to `float` or to `integer`.

Also note that it is not possible to directly use the built-in `int` function to construct an integer from a string with decimals, to overcome this I'm using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/), where `g` will print a given number as a fixed-point number, with in this case `0` decimal places:

```
l = ['67.50', '70.00', '72.50', '75.00', '77.50', '80.00', '82.50']

[int(f'{float(i):g}') if float(i)%1 == 0. else float(i) for i in l]
# [67.5, 70, 72.5, 75, 77.5, 80, 82.5]
```

For python versions under `3.6` use `.format` for string formatting:

```
[int('{0:g}'.format(float(i))) if float(i)%1 == 0. else float(i) for i in l]
# # [67.5, 70, 72.5, 75, 77.5, 80, 82.5]
```

Comment: What about `70` ?

Comment: What about it @devesh?

Comment: I mean the code will throw an exception if `'70'` is an element in the list

Comment: Well that is assuming there are integers, but apparently all numbers are decimals

Comment: Updated @DeveshKumarSingh should work now with ints too

Answer (score 1):

Well this works, but there's probably a better way. It handles the case like 75.00 which you want to convert to integer and not a float.

```
from math import floor
list = ['67.50', '70.00', '72.50', '75.00', '77.50', '80.00', '82.50']
print([int(floor(float(l))) if float(l)-floor(float(l)) == 0 else float(l) for l in list])
```

Output is

```
python test.py
[67.5, 70, 72.5, 75, 77.5, 80, 82.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another version:

```
list = ['67.50', '70.00', '72.50', '75.00', '77.50', '80.00', '82.50']

new_list = []

for x in list:
    float_x = float(x)
    int_x = int(float_x)
    if int_x == float_x:
        new_list.append(int_x)
    else:
        new_list.append(float_x)

for y in new_list:
    print(type(y))
```

Returns:

```
<class 'float'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'float'>
```