# Printing certain strings different colour with termcolor.colored?

Tags: python, colors

I would like to print certain strings in different colours in Python. I need to modify the code:

```
board_p1 = []
board_pc = []

board_size=6

for x in range(board_size):
    board_p1.append(["[W]"] * board_size)
    board_pc.append(["[W]"] * board_size)

def print_board(board):
    if board == board_p1:
        print colored("\n   Computers Board:    ",attrs=['underline'])
        for row in board:
            print " ".join(colored(element,"cyan") if element != "[X]" else colored(element,"red") if element != "[H]" else colored(element,"magenta") for element in row)
    if board == board_pc:
        print colored("\n    Players Board:     ",attrs=['underline'])
        for row in board_pc:
            print " ".join(colored(element,"cyan") if element != "[S]" else colored(element,"green") if element != "[X]" else colored(element,"red") if element != "[H]" else colored(element,"magenta") for element in row)
```

so that when in the list an `[H]` will be printed as a magenta, an `[X]` will be in red, etc I can have an output like:

[image]

I am having difficulty with:

```
print " ".join(colored(element,"cyan") if element != "[S]" else colored(element,"green") if element != "[X]" else colored(element,"red") if element != "[H]" else colored(element,"magenta") for element in row)
```

in order to print in the aforementioned way.

**Q:** How can I modify/edit the line of code above, so that if the [X] is seen in the list that it's printed as red, [S] in green and [H] in magenta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the following would parse correctly due to the added parentheses:

```
print " ".join(colored(element,"cyan") if element != "[S]" else (colored(element,"green") if element != "[X]" else (colored(element,"red") if element != "[H]" else colored(element,"magenta"))) for element in row)
```

However due to the negated conditions, I wasn't able to tell if it would produce the mapping described and depicted in the example in your question.

But going from that description I would suggest that it would be better to use a dictionary like this:

```
element_colors = {'[W]': 'cyan', '[X]': 'red', '[S]': 'green', '[H]': 'magenta'}

print " ".join(colored(element, element_colors[element]) for element in row)
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you so much! I prefer your suggestion with the dictionary as it's a simpler and more efficient way of doing the task!