# How to do List flattening inside the loop with list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

here i am having list of dictionaries, my goal is to iterate over list and whenever there is 2 or more list available, i want to merge them and append in a output list, and whenever there is only one list it needs to be stored as it as.

```
data = [
            [[{'font-weight': '1'},{'font-weight': '1'}],[{'font-weight': '2'},{'font-weight': '2'}]],
            [{'font-weight': '3'},{'font-weight': '3'},{'font-weight': '3'}],
            [[{'font-weight': '1'},{'font-weight': '1'}],[{'font-weight': '2'},{'font-weight': '2'}]],
            [{'font-weight': '3'},{'font-weight': '3'}]
        ]
```

I can do list flattening for particular element `data[0]`

```
print([item for sublist in data[0] for item in sublist])
[{'font-weight': '1'}, {'font-weight': '1'}, {'font-weight': '2'}, {'font-weight': '2'}]
```

Expected output :

```
data = [
            [{'font-weight': '1'},{'font-weight': '1'},{'font-weight': '2'},{'font-weight': '2'}],
            [{'font-weight': '3'},{'font-weight': '3'},{'font-weight': '3'}],
            [{'font-weight': '1'},{'font-weight': '1'},{'font-weight': '2'},{'font-weight': '2'}]
            [{'font-weight': '3'},{'font-weight': '3'}]
        ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [conditional list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension) with [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) for those elements which need flattening:

```
In [54]: import itertools

In [55]: [list(itertools.chain(*l)) if isinstance(l[0], list) else l for l in data]
Out[55]: 
[[{'font-weight': '1'},
  {'font-weight': '1'},
  {'font-weight': '2'},
  {'font-weight': '2'}],
 [{'font-weight': '3'}, {'font-weight': '3'}, {'font-weight': '3'}],
 [{'font-weight': '1'},
  {'font-weight': '1'},
  {'font-weight': '2'},
  {'font-weight': '2'}],
 [{'font-weight': '3'}, {'font-weight': '3'}]]
```

Comment: @Rahul Thanks! I like your answer too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
result = []
for item in data:
    result.append([i for j in item for i in j])
```

Single line code with list comprehension,

```
[[i for j in item for i in j] for item in data]
```

Alternative method,

```
import numpy as np
[list(np.array(i).flat) for i in data]
```

**Result**

```
[[{'font-weight': '1'},
  {'font-weight': '1'},
  {'font-weight': '2'},
  {'font-weight': '2'}],
 [{'font-weight': '3'}, {'font-weight': '3'}, {'font-weight': '3'}],
 [{'font-weight': '1'},
  {'font-weight': '1'},
  {'font-weight': '2'},
  {'font-weight': '2'}],
 [{'font-weight': '3'}, {'font-weight': '3'}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

iterate through list and check if each item is lists of list. If so flatten it.

---

```
data = [
         [[{'font-weight': '1'},{'font-weight': '1'}],[{'font-weight': '2'},{'font-weight': '2'}]],
         [{'font-weight': '3'},{'font-weight': '3'},{'font-weight': '3'}],
         [[{'font-weight': '1'},{'font-weight': '1'}],[{'font-weight': '2'},{'font-weight': '2'}]],
         [{'font-weight': '3'},{'font-weight': '3'}]
       ]
for n, each_item in enumerate(data):
   if any(isinstance(el, list) for el in each_item):
        data[n] = sum(each_item, [])

print data
```