# How to add else in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I have some troubles with next statement:

```
demo = json.loads(raw)
c = 'Return To Sender (Dub Mix)'
for i in (i for i, tr in enumerate(demo['tracks']) if c in tr['title']):
     print(i)
```

It works as it should, but how to add *else*, becouse `c` not always in `tr['title']`

The `demo` object:

```
{
'mixes': [],
'packs': [],
'stems': [],
'tracks': [{
    'id': 7407969,
    'mix': 'Original Mix',
    'name': 'Return To Sender',
    'title': 'Return To Sender (Original Mix)',
}, {
    'id': 7407971,
    'mix': 'Matrey Remix',
    'name': 'Return To Sender',
    'title': 'Return To Sender (Matrey Remix)',
}, {
    'id': 9011142,
    'mix': 'Matrey Remix',
    'name': 'Return To Sender',
    'title': 'Return To Sender (Matrey Remix)',
}, {
    'id': 7846774,
    'mix': 'Matrey Remix',
    'name': 'Return To Sender',
    'title': 'Return To Sender (Matrey Remix)',
}, {
    'id': 7407969,
    'mix': 'Original Mix',
    'name': 'Return To Sender',
    'title': 'Return To Sender (Original Mix)',
}, {
    'id': 9011141,
    'mix': 'Original Mix',
    'name': 'Return To Sender',
    'type': 'track',
}, {
    'id': 7789328,
    'mix': 'Original Mix',
    'name': 'Return To Sender',
    'title': 'Return To Sender (Original Mix)',
}]
```

}

Comment: Please correct the non-English characters

Comment: Simply add else after print(i) for else we don't  need to check any condition so add else:

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi: Already fixed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if/else in Python's list comprehension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension)

Comment: disclaimer: not down voter, but please consider adding runnable code. Where does `c` spring up from?

Comment: @PaulRooney:
Thanks for the help, sometimes i forget about the rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
for i, tr in enumerate(demo['tracks']):
    if c in tr['title']:
        print(i)
    else:
        pass # do something else
```

But if you must have it in the generator expression, you have to replace the filter if at the end of the for loop `for`-`in`-`if` with `if`-`else`-`for`-`in`:

```
for i in (i if c in tr['title'] else None for i, tr in enumerate(demo['tracks'])):
    print(i)
```

See [if else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension/4406400)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one liner!.

guessing you only wants to print (i) when condition gets true

```
 for i in (i for i, tr in enumerate(demo['tracks']):
     print(i) if c in tr['title']) else ''
```