# if else to raise a ValueError

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, valueerror

I am following this:

[if else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

but the following small program is generating a syntax error:

```
def to_rna(dnasequences):
    xlate = {'G': 'C', 'C': 'G', 'T': 'A', 'A': 'U'}
    return ''.join(xlate[sequence] for sequence in dnasequences if sequence in xlate.keys() else raise ValueError)
```

The else clause is generating the error.

If I remove the else clause it runs, however, I want to raise a ValueError for any input
that is NOT a key in my dictionary 'xlate'.

*NOTE* I am working on the rna-transcription problem from exercism.io.

I pass 5 unit tests but I fail the three unit tests requiring a ValueError for invalid input.

Comment: If you can't make the one-liner work, that's a good indication that you're trying to do too much. Just write a normal loop instead.

Comment: If you insist to do it inline, and since you care not about the message anyway, instead of the `raise ValueError` statement just place `int("")` and it will raise a `ValueError` for you. Or, you know, ditch the list comprehension and unwrap your loop to do it properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this in a comprehension. The conditional expression has the form:

```
expr if expr else expr
```

<sup><sup>(and, sub-note, it should be used in the beginning of the comprehension)</sup></sup>

while `raise ExceptionClass` [is a statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement), not an expression. As such, a `SyntaxError` is raised.

In short, if you do want to use `raise`, you'll have to resort to a `for` loop.

---

Alternately, if you're just very passionate about comprehensions, you could define a function which you can then call in the `else` clause:

```
def raiser(exc_type):
    raise exc_type
```

This is because function calls are expressions. Of course, this is quite ugly.

Comment: "while raise ExceptionClass is a statement, not an expression." That's what I missed.

Comment: Interesting. Is there really no way to do a `raise` statement inside an expression? Even a `lambda` won't help. In extension, @zwer's idea with a message like `int("Hi I am an error")` seems to be the closest thing I can think of. Or the extra method, of course. But yeah, that's rather ugly.

Comment: @Jeronimo directly, no. The bodies of `lambda`s only [accept expressions too](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-lambda_expr). Indirect approaches such as `int` or a helper function are the only (ugly) options here.