# change string in list to upper cases

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I want to only find the values in the list which are strings, and change them to upper case.

If `lst` is not a list I want to return `-1`.

For the below example, the output should be: `[11, 'TEST', 3.14, 'CASE']`.

```
lst =  [11, 'TeSt', 3.14, 'cAsE']
def upper_strings(lst):
    if type(lst)!= list:
        lst = -1
    else:
        for char in lst:
            if type(char) == str:
                char=char.upper()
            else:
                char == char
    return lst
print(upper_strings(lst))
```

The output that I got was:

```
[11, 'TeSt', 3.14, 'cAsE']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def upper_strings(lst):   
  if not isinstance(lst, list):
    return -1 
  else:
    return [x.upper() if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in lst]
print(upper_strings(lst))
```

See here for information on list comprehensions:
[if else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Comment: ok, that's good thank you but I don't want to change the char that are not str to -1 I want to leave them as they are, only if the input list is not a list I want to return -1

Comment: Modified, please check again.