# How to write a for loop and multiple if statements in one line?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

Is there a way to write something like this in one line?

```
for x in list: 
   if condition1: 
       (...) 
   elif condition2: 
       (...) 
   else: 
       (...)
```

Another way of asking is: Is it possible to combine following list comprehensions?

```
(...) for x in list
```

and

```
123 if condition1 else 345 if condition2 else 0
```

Comment: I recommend that you don't write this in one line.

Comment: does this answer satisfy your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension

Comment: Thanks @brettmichaelgreen I suddenly realized what I missed because of your link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do would almost certainly be considered bad style. Maybe it's an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? In that case, you should open another question with the underlying issue.

If you're sure this is what you want, have a look at the following example, using 
[PEP 308 -- Conditional Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/)
:

```py
>>> def f(condition1, condition2):
...     return 1 if condition1 else 2 if condition2 else 3
... 
>>> f(True, False)
1
>>> f(True, True)
1
>>> f(False, True)
2
>>> f(False, False)
3
```

Subsequently, your example

```py
for x in list: 
   if condition1: 
       (...) 
   elif condition2: 
       (...) 
   else: 
       (...)
```

could be written as a list comprehension as follows:

```py
[(...) if condition1 else (...) if condition2 else (...) for x in list]
```

Answer (score 1):

use lsit comprehensions

var = [i for i in list if i == something or i == something] 
more on that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are ways, but not recommended.
Here is an example of how you could do it:

```py
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

for x in l:
  if x%2 == 0:
    print("Even")
  elif x%2 == 1:
    print("Odd")
  else:
    print("Nothing")

print("And here the one-liner:")

[print("Even") if x%2 == 0 else print("Odd") if x%2 == 1 else print("Nothing") for x in l]
```

I don't recommend this way, because of readability.
Read [The Zen of Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python), don't make too long lines (max 80 characters)

Answer (score 0):

The way to write **for loop** *in a single line*, mostly used in Data Science Project, You can use this way, as we have six labeled fake news LIAR:

Labels: ['barely-true' 'false' 'half-true' 'mostly-true' 'pants-fire' 'true'], to represent this as a binary labels:

We use the following way:

```
labels = [ 1 if lab=='false' or lab=='pants-fire' or lab=='barely_true'  else 0 for lab in df.is_fake]
```

Another way, the same if-else condition **for loop**:

```
labels = [ 1 if lab=='false' else 1 if lab=='pants-fire' else 1 if lab=='barely_true'  else 0 if lab == 'true' else 0 if lab == 'half-true' else 0 for lab in df.is_rumor]
```

Hope to help many of you, who want to do the same way in many problem-solving.