# Removing specific character from the end of strings in list in python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list that is something like this:

```
lst = ['Joe C', 'Jill', 'Chad', 'Cassie C']
```

I want to remove the last character from each string if that character is a 'C'. At the moment I'm stuck at this impass:

```
no_c_list = [i[:-1] for i in lst if i[-1:] == 'C']
```

However, this would return a list of:

```
['Joe', 'Cassie']
```

Comment: Do you plan on leaving the space between the 'C' and name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if else in a list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip):

```
lst = ['Joe C', 'Jill', 'Chad', 'Cassie C']

result = [e.rstrip('C') for e in lst]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['Joe ', 'Jill', 'Chad', 'Cassie ']
```

From the documentation:

> Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. The
>   chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be
>   removed.

Also, as mentioned by @dawg:

```
result = [e.rstrip(' C') for e in lst]
```

If you want to remove the trailing whitespace also.

Comment: Or `[e.rstrip(' C') for e in lst]` if you don't want the trailing space...

Comment: Note that this will incorrectly remove `'CC'` from `'Joe CC'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
lst = ['Joe C', 'Jill', 'Chad', 'Cassie C']

new_list = [ i[:-2] if i[-2:] == " C" else i for i in lst ]
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
>>> lst = ['Joe C', 'Jill', 'Chad', 'Cassie C']
>>> import re
>>> [re.sub(r' C$', '', s) for s in lst]
['Joe', 'Jill', 'Chad', 'Cassie']
```