# How to count the number of rows containing both a value in a set of columns and another value in another column in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

```
# import packages, set nan
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
nan = np.nan
```

---

### The problem

I have a dataframe, with a certain number of *observations* as columns, *measurements* as rows. The results of the *observations* are `A, B, C, D ...` . It also has a *category* column, which denote the *category* of the *measurement*. Categories: `a, b, c, d ...`. If a column contains a `nan` in a row, that means that the observation during that measurement has not been made (so `nan` is not an `observation`, it is lack of it). An [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
data = {'observation0': ['A','A','A','A','B'],'observation1': ['B','B','B','C',nan], 'category': ['a', 'b', 'c','a','b']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

`df` looks like this:

[image]

I would like to count how many times each observational result (ie `A, B, C, D...`) is observed using each category of measurement (ie `a, b, c, d ...`).

I would like to get:

```
obs_A_in_cat_a    2
obs_A_in_cat_b    1
obs_A_in_cat_c    1
obs_B_in_cat_a    1
obs_B_in_cat_b    2
obs_B_in_cat_c    1
obs_C_in_cat_a    1
obs_C_in_cat_b    0
obs_C_in_cat_c    0
```

Observation `A` appears in rows with `index` `0` and `3` (see above df) while the measurement `category` is `a`, so `obs_A_in_cat_a` is `2`. Observation `A` appears only once (row `index` `1`) in a measurement with `category`: `b`, so `obs_A_in_cat_b` is `1`, and so on.

---

### My solution

First I gather the outcomes of observations, [taking care not to include nans](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
observations = pd.unique(pd.concat([df[col] for col in df.columns if 'observation' in col]).dropna())
```

The different categories they belong to:

```
categories = pd.unique(df['category'])
```

Then, iterate through observations. If it is relying on [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/apply-function-to-every-row-in-a-pandas-dataframe/),

```
for observation in observations:
    for category in categories:
        df['obs_'+observation+'_in_cat_'+category]=\
        df.apply(lambda row: int(observation in [row[col]
                                                 for col in df.columns
                                                 if 'observation' in col]
                                 and row['category'] == category),axis=1)
```

The lambda function checks if `observation` appears in each `row`, and that the measurement is in the category which is currently considered in the iteration. New columns are created, with headers obs_OBSERVATION_in_cat_CATEGORY, where `OBSERVATION` is `A, B, C, D ...`, `CATEGORY` is `a, b, c, d ...` If an `observationX` in a `categoryY` was made during a measurement, `obs_OBSERVATIONX_in_cat_CATEGORYY` is `1` in the row corresponding to that measurement, otherwise it is `0`.

The resulting `df` (parts of it) looks like this:

[image]

Finish using [`sum()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)ming the values of the newly created columns, selecting those with a [conditional list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406777/8565438):

```
df[[col for col in df.columns if '_in_cat_' in col]].sum()
```

This gives me the output which I'd like to get, shown above. [Whole notebook here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vmrAi1YhMx62jN8B4jSqDvtxHAWEchT1?usp=sharing).

---

### The question

This method seem to work, but it is too slow to be easily applicable in real life. How could I make it quicker? I am looking for something like:

```
how_many_times_each_observation_was_made_using_each_category_of_measurement(
df,
list_of_observation_columns,
category_column)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solutuion with `MultiIndex` with [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) for count values, add `0` for missing combinations by [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
s = df.melt('category').groupby(['value','category']).size()
s = s.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product(s.index.levels), fill_value=0)
print (s)
value  category
A      a           2
       b           1
       c           1
B      a           1
       b           2
       c           1
C      a           1
       b           0
       c           0
dtype: int64
```

Last is possible flatten it by `f-string`s:

```
s.index = s.index.map(lambda x: f'obs_{x[0]}_in_cat_{x[1]}')   
print (s)
obs_A_in_cat_a    2
obs_A_in_cat_b    1
obs_A_in_cat_c    1
obs_B_in_cat_a    1
obs_B_in_cat_b    2
obs_B_in_cat_c    1
obs_C_in_cat_a    1
obs_C_in_cat_b    0
obs_C_in_cat_c    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 4):

You could combine [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) with [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to get your output :

```
s = df.melt("category")
s = pd.crosstab(s.value, s.category).stack()
s.index = [f"obs_{first}_in_cat_{last}" for first, last in s.index]

s

obs_A_in_cat_a    2
obs_A_in_cat_b    1
obs_A_in_cat_c    1
obs_B_in_cat_a    1
obs_B_in_cat_b    2
obs_B_in_cat_c    1
obs_C_in_cat_a    1
obs_C_in_cat_b    0
obs_C_in_cat_c    0
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in the following way:

```
dfT = []
for colName in ['observation0','observation1']:
    df1 = df.groupby([colName,'category'])['category'].count().to_frame()
    df1.columns = ['count']
    df1 = df1.reset_index()
    df1['label'] = 'obs_'+df1[colName]+'_cat_'+df1['category']
    df1 = df1.loc[:,['label','count']]
    dfT.append(df1)

dfT = pd.concat(dfT,axis=0).reset_index(drop=True)
```