# Removing all values bigger than desired number from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
L=[10,19,20,30,8,11,9]
i=0
while i==0:
    while L[i]<=12:
        i+=1
    else:
        L.pop(i)
        i=0
```

Hello, I want to remove values, which are bigger than 12, from the list. I get the list I want, but I also get an error message, which says "list index out of range" even though I make i=0 at the end of loop. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Answer (score 3):

You can do, using a [conditional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406777/8565438) [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it/34932520):

```
l=[each for each in L if each<=12]
```

`l` will be:

```
[10, 8, 11, 9]
```

---

If you don't like list comprehension, you can do:

```
l=[]
for each in L:
    if each<=12:
        l.append(each)
```

`l` will be the same as before.

Comment: Is there any solution without list comprehension?

Comment: Thanks, so I always need to create a new list in such problems, right?

Comment: Well, you can name the result of the list comprehension `L` as well, if that makes it easier (it'll be a new list though, under the hood).

Comment: @blitz1 No, you can also modify the existing list.

Answer (score 2):

When you do a `pop()`, you are changing the list by shortening it. If you want to do the `pop()` call, I suggest parsing the list in reverse order, starting at the end and working towards the beginning.

```
for i in range(len(L) - 1, -1, -1):
    if L[i] > 12:
        L.pop(i)
```

But, to directly answer your question, change your code to replace:

```
L.pop(i)
```

with:

```
if i < len(L):
    L.pop(i)
```

That should make your actual error go away. But it's not the best way to handle the problem. I would still suggest processing the list in reverse order.

Comment: And although a list comprehension is a better way to implement this problem, it may not be the best solution for a newer coder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter`:

```
L=[10,19,20,30,8,11,9]

#For python 2
L1 = filter(lambda x: x < 12, L)

#For python 3, wrap filter with list
L1 = list(filter(lambda x: x < 12, L))

print (L1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with while and without creating a new list

```
L=[10,19,20,30,8,11,9]
i=0
while i < len(L):
    if L[i] > 12:
        L.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1
```

Comment: I would prefer using @zabop's [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63971813/14277722). It's usually not a good idea to manipulate a list inplace.

Answer (score 0):

though this is not the best way of doing it, but it may be the desired fix you are looking for

```
L=[10,19,20,30,8,11,9]
i=0
while i==0:
  while L[i]<=12:
    if i==len(L)-1:
      break
    i+=1
  else:
    L.pop(i)
    i=0
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `pandas` for simpler answer

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10,19,20,30,8,11,9]})
final_list = df[df['A'] <= 12]['A'].values.tolist()
```

Simplest answer