# Obtaining synsets in relation to their parts of speech tags

Tags: nltk

I want to get the corresponding synsets in piece of text in relation to their parts of speech tag.
For example, if you type,

```
print('Synsets nouns : {}'.format(wn.synsets('title', pos = 'n')))
out : [Synset('title.n.01'),Synset('title.n.02'),Synset('title.n.03'), ...]
```

You end up with a whole lot of synonyms just in relation to only nouns (if there were any verbs for example they will be ignored).

Instead of manually typing `pos = 'n'` I want to automatize it for a sentence.

For example:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

text = 'Theim won his first ever grandslam title'
text_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
text_posTags = nltk.pos_tag(text_tokens)

corresponding_synsets = [wn.synsets(i[0], pos = i[1]) for i in text_posTags]
```

But now I end up with an error since text_posTags are in a different format,
for example the word 'title' will have pos named 'NN' rather than 'n'.

```
print(text_posTags)
out:
[('Theim', 'NNP'), ('won', 'VBD'), ('his', 'PRP$'), ('first', 'JJ'), ('ever', 'RB'), ('grandslam', 'VBP'), ('title', 'NN')]
```

Any ideas to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

You may already be aware that NLTK uses the [Penn Treebank tagset](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) to represent different classes within the same part of speech (e.g. proper noun vs noun).

If I understood your issue correctly, one possible solution would be to handle for all the possible referents of a noun:

```
noun_types = ['NN', 'NNP', 'NNS', 'NNPS']
tag = 'NN'

if tag in noun_types:
    print('n')
```

If you went with the above approach and wanted to include a conditional in your list comprehension, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406389/if-else-in-a-list-comprehension) might be a useful resource.